# Pie Chart not created when one record in data uses Flot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

If only one record in data then pie chart not display. I'm using Flot chart.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    var data = [{
        label: "Series1",
        data: 1
    }, ];
    $.plot($("#graph11"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                radius: 1,
                tilt: 0.5,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 1,
                    formatter: function (label, series) {
                        return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">' + label + '<br/>' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%</div>';
                    },
                    background: {
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }
                },
                combine: {
                    color: '#999',
                    threshold: 0.1
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When only one record in data then pie chart not display.

Comment: it perfectly running check this http://jsfiddle.net/7VM8w/

Comment: THERE'S NO NEED FOR THE CAPS.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.  I get a "Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" error from flot.pie.min.js.

Comment: My solution was to use a different version of Flot.  Not sure which version though -- I'll look it up if someone is interested.

Comment: I had the same problem. The fix for me was to download the latest jquery.flot.pie.js from or link directly to it (might not be such a good idea) http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js

Comment: @johnpaulhayes your solution works! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine.

**Except**

If you are running this in older versions of IE (<=7):

```
var data = [{
    label: "Series1",
    data: 1
}, ];  // <--remove the trailing comma
```

[It'll die on the trailing comma.](http://trailingcomma.com/)

Comment: Not quite the solution but none the less a valid comment.